# Как правильно организовать проверку пользовательского ввода в консольной программе C#

Tags: c#, .net

Всем доброго времени суток. Скажите, как правильно организовать проверку пользовательского ввода в консоль по примеру имени. Предположим, что-бы нельзя было вводить символы по типу !"№;%%:?* и т.д. а также цифры, автоматически первая буква делалась с верхним регистром, имя не более 30 символов. В случае неправильного ввода указывалась причина отказа и предлогалась ввести имя заново.

Comment: Длину строки проверить не можете, или в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как правильно это все организовать. Создать для каждой отдельной проверки свой метод в отдельном классе и потом в верхнем уровне поочередно вызывать эти методы из класса и в параметры вставлять переменную строки?

Comment: Ну, для начала здесь организовывать нечего, достаточно начать писать код исходя непосредственно из задачи. После ввода провести ряд проверок строки на требуемые условия, если проверка не прошла, вернуть ошибку и прекратить дальнешие проверки. Разбейте код на методы, пишите каждый метод для каждой подзадачи отдельно, так проще будет сориентироваться.

Answer (score 0):

Не забудь подключить Linq в свой проект

```
    static bool _flag;
    static char[] symbols = { '#', '@', '№' }; //Запрещенные символы
    static int size = 30; // Минимальная длина сообщения

    static bool Check_correctly(string text)
    {
        if (text.Length < size){
            Console.WriteLine("Размер сообщения слишком мал");
            return true;
        }

        bool check = text.Where(symb => symbols.Contains(symb)).ToArray().Length > 0;

        if (check){
            Console.WriteLine("Неверно введено сообщение");
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
            _flag = Check_correctly(Console.ReadLine());
        while (_flag);

        Console.WriteLine("Все хорошо, проходите дальше");
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]